# cocos2d-x with XCODE setup on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to setup cocos2d-x in the command line and I keep running into -bash: export: `Development/cocos2d-x-3.14/tools/cocos2d-console/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export:`Development/cocos2d-x-3.14/templates': not a valid identifier

Here is a screen shot of my process. Any advice or how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

[Image of Termnal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOWYQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think your bash .profile has a relative path for cocos2d-x. Edit your .profile to add a `~/` in front of `Development/cocos2d0x...` and then try again with the `source` command.